# Simulate cleaned activity android

Tags: android, destroy, activity-lifecycle

Whenever an Android app has been running for 30+ minutes, there is the possibility the current activity gets cleaned. I don't know exactly what all will be cleaned but my issue is the following.

Whenever the app has been in the background for a long period, which seems starts at about 30 minutes. The Activity might have been "cleaned" resulting in a null pointer somewhere.
My baseActivity has set a default throwable handler using:
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler, which resets all variables and returns to a loginscreen.

I know I can't let anyone else debug my app for me, but is there some way I could simulate those cleanups android executes every xx minutes? Because waiting an hour every time is a pain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Developer options for this:

Go to *Settings* > *Developer options* > under "apps" enable *Don't keep activities*

this destroys the activity as soon as you leave it (pressing home button or some other way)

Comment: I found out my bug, but imma try this out.

Comment: Hmm strange it doesn't seem to do anything, do I need to rebuild the app? or set it as debug app.

Comment: Maybe it's because I'm currently on a Samsung these seem to have some issues sometimes. I'll come back later when I checked this on a nexus.

Comment: @MathijsSegers, you have to leave the activity after you have created it. (like pressing home) Usually android keeps the activity alive, in case the user comes back to it. Here, the activity is killed as soon as the user leaves it. You were having issues to kill the activity, and to start it clean, this will do as you asked in your question.

Comment: @MathijsSegers The device type should not be a barrier here. if it is > ICS, this should work, although in my defence, samsung may have a different implementation for this

Comment: Yeah I enabled the option but I when I press home, re-open the app the activity is still alive, so are is the stack when I press the back button.

So I did what you said but for some reason it had no effect. imo I think it's samsung's fault ;).

Comment: @MathijsSegers, you can read a post about this: https://plus.google.com/+CyrilMottier/posts/XUa3bZrEEgk, maybe it'll help you in future, if this kind of functionalities arise.

Comment: It will use it anyways. I mostly develop on a different device and this feature seems a must to test since our app is not a simple one.

Thanks.